# Tabulate accuracy and mean for each fold in GridSearchCV from scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm doing a grid search over my model in scikit-learn, Python3, with two parameter sets A and B. The code looks like this:

```
parameterA = ['a', 'b']
parameterB = np.array([10, 100])
param_grid = dict(parameterA=parameterA, parameterB=parameterB)
model = buildModel()
grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring="accuracy")
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
for parameters, scores in grid_result.grid_scores_:
    print("Mean: " + scores.mean())
    print("Parameters: " + parameters)
```

- Did I understand correctly, that the score.mean() is the mean of the accuracies?
- How can I put in my own scoring function? In the documentation, it says with "scorer(estimator, X, y)". Where do I get X and y from? Aren't they the training and test set of the cross-validation? Are they accessible?
- Is it possible to get all those values for *each* fold of the cross validation? By default, there are k=3 folds, so I'd expect three times a mean and an accuracy for each parameter combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should not use `grid_scores_` anymore since it was deprecated in version **0.18** in favor of `cv_results_` attribute. The `grid_scores_` attribute will not be available from version **0.20**.

---

**Q°** : *Did I understand correctly, that the score.mean() is the mean of the accuracies?*

**A** : The attribute `cv_results_` actually returns a dictionnary of all the metrics you are looking for. Check this out : [`cv_result_`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

---

**Q°** : *Is it possible to get all those values for each fold of the cross validation? By default, there are k=3 folds, so I'd expect three times a mean and an accuracy for each parameter combination.*

**A** : Yes, actually you'll need to use the attribute `verbose`. `verbose` must be an integer and it controls the verbosity: the higher, the more messages. For instance you could set `verbose=3`.

---

**Q°** : *How can I put in my own scoring function?*

**A** : Use [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) after you've defined a **loss function**. Your loss function must have the following signature : `score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)`. A basic loss function could be the ratio of well classified samples to the number of total samples (you can imagine any kind of metrics that would give you a good idea of how your classifier performs).

You would do like this :

```
def my_loss_func(y, y_pred):
    return np.sum(y == y_pred)/float(len(y_pred))

my_scorer = make_scorer(my_loss_func, greater_is_better=True)
```

And then you can use your `scorer` in your GridSearch.

Comment: If I use `verbose=100`, I get `[CV] .......... parameterA=b, parameterB=10, score=0.683594 -   0.1s`. Can I select this score (which is what I wanted) computationally?

Comment: I don't really get your question. What do you want to select ? The score or the parameters that give back this score ?

Comment: Something like `grid_result.fold_score`, that gives me a list of the score values.

Comment: @ste If I understand your question correctly, `cv_results_` contains all you need.